# FCM plugin for ionic ios app not working

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

We are trying to use fcm push notification in our ionic 2 app. But we are not able to call any method of fcm plugin(getToken, onTokenRefresh etc). Same ionic code and fcm plugins are working for android.

We are trying to use cordova-plugin-fcm. It seems like getToken method is not getting called or it is running forever.

We have enabled Push Notifications in xCode. Still it is not working.

Please suggest how to resolve it.

Comment: I am also facing same error. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Nopes... instead I started working on phonegap push plugin.. this one working fine yet.

Comment: Same here. I also moved to above plugin. :P